# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter - c#

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I want to get datetime.now and pass like a parameter for api point from this method:

```
string GenerateRequestUriData(string endpoint, string dateQuery, string num, int statNum)
    {
        DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now;

        dateQuery = dateNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        num = daysBeforeData;

        statNum = getStationNumber;

        string requestUri = endpoint;
        requestUri += "/hqdataahs/GetData?";
        requestUri += $"date={dateQuery}&";
        requestUri += $"num={num}&";
        requestUri += $"statNum={statNum}&";

        return requestUri;
    }
```

In other method I try to receive data from API like this:

```
async void OnButtonClicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var result = await _restServiceStations.Get_HQ_AHS(GenerateRequestUriData(Constants.EndPoint));
    }
```

But I receive error:

```
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'dateQuery' of 'HQ_AHS.GenerateRequestUriData(string, string, string, int)'
```

Is there a way to fix this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the signature of `GenerateRequestUriData` has **four** parameters

```
GenerateRequestUriData(string endpoint, string dateQuery, string num, int statNum)
```

you are only passing **ONE**

```
GenerateRequestUriData(Constants.EndPoint)
```

you either need to pass all the required parameters, or set default values for them

Comment: Can you show me how ?

Comment: you need to invest some time reading a C# book.  These are basic C# concepts.  ie, `GenerateRequestUriData(Constants.EndPoint, "parm1", "parm2", 3);`